# Laravel 7, utilização de foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Bom dia, 
estou a fazer um pequeno projeto em Laravel 7 e é a primeira vez que utilizo Foreign Key e relaciono duas tabelas de Base de Dados. Em ambos os Models das respetivas tabelas já coloquei uma relação de One To One. Ao criar um produto e ao fazer salvar dá-me este erro, "General error: 1364 Field 'id_form' doesn't have a default value", o id_form é a foreign key. Tenho uma tabela de Base de Dados chamada form que tem um id, depois tenho uma tabela question que via buscar o id do form.

Para desenvolver a aplicação juntei as duas tabelas de base de dados no mesmo Controller, sendo isto o que tenho no Controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name_form' =>'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
            //'data_type' => 'required',
            'question' => 'required'
        ]);

        $form = new Forms([
            'name_form' => $request->get('name_form'),
            'description'=> $request->get('description'),
            'email'=> $request->get('email'),
            'end_date' => $request->get('end_date')           
        ]);

        $question = new Questions([
            //'data_type'=> $request->get('data_type'),
            'question'=> $request->get('question')
        ]);

        $form->save();
        $question->save();

        return redirect('/backoffice/forms')->with('success', 'O formulário foi criado com sucesso.');
    }
```

Será que alguém me consegue ajudar para que a tabela questions vá buscar o id do form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está passando a "chave" `id_form` para sua model Questions ela deve ter o id da sua chave primaria da outra tabela conforme os dados passados para essa função através da requisição.
Deveria ser:

```
$question = new Questions([
    //'data_type'=> $request->get('data_type'),
    'question'=> $request->get('question'),
    'id_form' => $id_do_formulario_relacionado_aqui
]);
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!